# Most efficient method for adding leading 0's to an int in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return two fields from a database concatenated as 'field1-field2'.  The second field is an int, but needs to be returned as a fixed length of 5 with leading 0's.  The method i'm using is:

```
SELECT Field1 + '-' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(Field2 AS varchar),5) FROM ...
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That is pretty much the way: [Adding Leading Zeros To Integer Values](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Adding_Leading_Zeros_To_Integer_Values)

So, to save following the link, the query looks like this, where `#Numbers` is the table and `Num` is the column:

```
   SELECT RIGHT('000000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),Num), 8) FROM #Numbers
```

for negative or positive values

```
declare @v varchar(6)
select @v = -5

SELECT case  when @v < 0 
then '-' else '' end + RIGHT('00000' + replace(@v,'-',''), 5)
```

Comment: This will generate an exception with a number due to conversions, you need the cast

Comment: Actually it doesn't generate an exception because it converts the '000000' to a int and does an add - still doesn't work though

Comment: The link provides the additional context for my specific issue.

Comment: please add information about [`lpad`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_lpad.asp) in yout answer

Answer (score 9):

Another way (without CAST or CONVERT):

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLACE(STR(@NUM),' ','0'),5)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford/want to have a function in your database you could use something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION LEFTPAD
           (@SourceString VARCHAR(MAX),
            @FinalLength  INT,
            @PadChar      CHAR(1)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN
    (SELECT Replicate(@PadChar, @FinalLength - Len(@SourceString)) + @SourceString)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this.

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 5) + CAST(Field2 AS VARCHAR(5),5)
```

Not necessarily all that "Easier", or more efficient, but better to read. Could be optimized to remove the need for "RIGHT"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a consistent number of total strings in the final result by adding different number of zeros, here is a little bit modification (for vsql)

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(
    REPEAT('0', 9-length(TO_CHAR(var1))), 
    CAST(var1 AS VARCHAR(9))
  ) as var1
```

You can replace 9 by any number for your need!

BRD