# Recognise a leading 0 in an int?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to insert an entry into a database:

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2) values (@number, @word);";

mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@number", MySqlDbType.Int32);
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@word", MySqlDbType.VarChar);

mySqlCommand.Parameters["@number"].Value = 0110;
mySqlCommand.Parameters["@word"].Value = "Hello";
```

However when I get it back out, it's stored as `110` instead of `0110`. How can I get it to recognise the leading `0`?

Comment: An integer has no concept of a leading 0, I'm afraid...

Comment: you can't unless you change your column type to soemthing else like varchar

Comment: I suppose that you should store number as `NVARCHAR` instead of `INT`. Otherwise, MSSQL always will be removing leading zeros.

Comment: Check [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778909/most-efficent-method-for-adding-leading-0s-to-an-int-in-sql)! question

Comment: Ben, try `Console.WriteLine(110 + " " + 0110);`

Comment: Do you know an integer that has a value 0110?? I know I don't. That's not a number, that is a string consisting of 4 digits and that's a huge difference.

Comment: Can I ask why you must have it with a leading zero? surely, it should only matter when you output the number to a user, in which case there is `PadLeft("0", 4)`

Comment: @walther arguably, it is a perfectly valid number; it is just entirely identical to 110.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well your datatype is integer. when 0110 is cast to integer it becomes 110.
To achieve your goal you need to set its datatype as varchar both in table and
`MySqlDbType.Int32`  to `MySqlDbType.VarChar`.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Or a decimal with a scale of 0 and a precision of 4 ?

Comment: I don't think so decimal will work. as 0110 is a type of varchar or string. 0 on left for integer value means nothing.

Comment: @PaulZahra, huh? That doesn't make any sense. If one needs a number with 4 digits and 0 decimal places, it's an integer. Anyway it wouldn't work either.

Comment: Wasn't sure if it left padded automatically... anyway wouldn't a simpler solution than altering the db be to use LPAD ? e.g. SELECT LPAD(110,4,'0') ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like leading 0 in int. however if u want to store the leading 0 then you can convert data type of that field to Varchar..

or by programmatically you can also pad 0 in any variable but again it will be converted to string.
Like this

```
int Anynumber= 5;

string AnynumberWithZero = string.Format("{0}", Anynumber.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
```

Result will be"05"