# How to add leading 0's to integer in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have date and time values that are stored (separately) as integers.
I now want to convert them into datetime data type into a new column but have trouble handling the time.

My first idea was to do it kinda like this (I can deal with the dates so in this example I'm just using a dummy date):

```
SET new_column = CAST(CONCAT('2020-01-01T', 
                             date_column / 10000, ':', 
                             date_column % 10000 / 100, ':', 
                             date_column % 100) AS DATETIME)
```

The issue is that `CAST` expects exactly the format 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss' but the calculation may sometimes only return one digit instead of the needed two digits for a part of the time.

For example the time one minute after 9am would result in the string '2020-01-01T9:1:0' though '2020-01-01T09:01:00' would be required.

Is there an efficient way to add leading 0s?

EDIT: The date_column contains integer values that represent times in the format hhmmss. So for example 10am would be stored as 100000, one minute after 9am would be stored as 90100.

I know that it is stupid to encode times/dates as integer. This is for legacy reasons and my current task is to fix it ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method for adding leading 0's to an int in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778909/most-efficient-method-for-adding-leading-0s-to-an-int-in-sql)

Comment: What is the *actual* value in the column (variable?) `@date_column`? There may well be a less convulated method here.

Comment: @Larnu every possible time of the day could be stored in the column

Comment: Then use the correct type, `time`

Comment: `'every possible time of the day'` isn't a valid `int` value...

Comment: `I have date and time values that are stored (separately) as integers` then you have a serious bug. Integers are neither dates nor time. They aren't portable, don't prevent invalid values, don't allow easier searching, prevent the use of date functions *and* waste space. Use the correct types, `date` for the date and `time` for the time of day.

Comment: If they're stored separately, where's the other column come into the equation? Or is there one column holding both values? Sample input and desired output would be helpful. Dealing with the date "separately" may not be necessary at all (or at least not lead to the best solution).

Comment: It always mystifies me when someone comes with a question that clearly mentions they're building a new column with the appropriate type, yet people still helpfully point out that the original way of storing the data is bad and leave it at that. Yes, it is; but if you want to move to a brave new world where it isn't, you'll still have to deal with the badness for at least one time.

Comment: It's worth noting, as well, that `CAST` doesn't expect exactly that format, but it *is* unambiguous (like `yyyyMMdd` is). If you use `(TRY_)CONVERT`, however, you can use a style code, which can often make things easier to deal with. Of course, without actual examples, I can't offer an alternative solution.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I disagree that it's taboo to mention bad design - those comments are equally valid for future readers who may be earlier in the process and can _prevent_ the situation in the first place. Advice here isn't always for the exclusive use of the OP.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Nowhere did I call it taboo, and in fact I'm a huge fan of hammering the point home that dates and times should be stored using the appropriate types, rather than the myriad alternative, poor ways of doing it. It just struck me as curious and unhelpful that more than one person felt the need to point it out without actually advancing an answer on the question (which is also a good and arguably even better place to stick that advice, incidentally).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't know, I comment all the time when I have advice that doesn't specifically answer the question and don't have an answer at the ready, because I think it's more helpful to mention it (again, both for the current OP and for future readers), but I'm starting to rethink my approach because I certainly have been getting more grief for my input than thanks.

Comment: @JeroenMostert People designing tables _this very moment_ are using the wrong data type and probably think it's the best possible design. What is wrong with mentioning that _this is bad design_ to someone who already seems to have realized it, if another reader who hasn't realized it yet may now read these comments and reconsider? It always mystifies _me_ when people consider questions here an independent, isolated, and self-contained support ticket, when really they are meant to be a longer-term resource for many future readers.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Your contributions to this site are appreciated -- by me and certainly also others, I'd hope. Please don't take my remark as personal criticism, or if you do, at least not the kind that's serious enough to warrant an extended discussion. Certainly my comment was *not* intended to target you as an individual, or make you feel that you needed to justify your actions to me, and I apologize for any irritation I've caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *pad* with a zero to deal with single-digit output. Unfortunately, T-SQL doesn't have a `PAD` or `RPAD` function, so you have to do it manually:

```
  SET new_column = CONVERT(datetime,
    CONCAT('2020-01-01T', 
        RIGHT(CONCAT('0', date_column / 10000),2)
      + ':'
      + RIGHT(CONCAT('0', date_column % 10000 / 100), 2)
      + ':'
      + RIGHT(CONCAT('0', date_column % 100), 2)));
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b80ce1abab8e1a0dd58d2851f5d64a9d)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of worrying about creating a string to be converted - convert the time to seconds and just add that to your date:

```
Declare @myDate int = 20220711
      , @myTime int = 182233;

 Select cast(@myDate As char(10))
      , @myTime / 10000 * 60 * 60
      , @myTime % 10000 / 100 * 60
      , @myTime % 100
      , dateadd(second, (@myTime / 10000 * 60 * 60) + (@myTime % 10000 / 100 * 60) + (@myTime % 100), cast(@myDate As char(10)))
```